# How to change an array element in state in a React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change an element of an array using the handleToggle method, but an error occurs, what am I doing wrong, and why should I always return a new array in the React?

Child component:

```
    function Todolist(props) {
      const todoItem = props.todos.map((todo, index) =>
        <ListItem key={todo.id} dense button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Checkbox checked={todo.completed} onChange={props.onChange(todo.id)} edge="start"/>
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={todo.title} />
          <ListItemSecondaryAction>
            <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="comments"></IconButton>
          </ListItemSecondaryAction>
        </ListItem>
      )
      return (
        <div>
          {todoItem}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Parent component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      todos: [
        {
          title: 'Learn React',
          id: Math.random(),
          completed: true
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  handleChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      value: evt.target.value
    })
  };

  handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const todos = [...this.state.todos];

    todos.push({
      title: this.state.value,
      id: Math.random(),
      completed: false
    });

    this.setState(state => ({
      todos,
      value: ''
    }))
  };

  handleToggle = (id) => {
    const todos = [...this.state.todos];

    todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        return todo.completed = !todo.completed
      } else {
        return todo
      }
    });

    this.setState(state => ({
      todos
    }))
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Grid className="Header" justify="center" container>
          <Grid item xs={11}>
            <h1 className="Title">My to-do react app</h1>
            <FormBox value={this.state.value} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <TodoList todos={this.state.todos} onChange={this.handleToggle} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Text of error:

Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are executing `onChange` immediately

```
onChange={props.onChange(todo.id)}
```

Wrap the callback in an `arrow function`

```
onChange={() => props.onChange(todo.id)}
```

Also your `handleToggle` isn't changing the values correctly (mutating), try like this

```
handleToggle = (id) => {
    const todos = [...this.state.todos];

    this.setState({ todos : todos.map(todo => ({
         ...todo, 
         completed : todo.id === id ? !todo.completed : todo.completed
     }) }))
  }
```

Comment: map returns a new array  so he should also collect the result into and array before setting it to state.

Comment: Hey man I think he wants to change only the todo with the specified id to completed

Comment: The error was because I forgot to wrap the returned object in `( )`. and yes (also missed that), I'm updating the answer

Comment: Thank you, my mistake was in callback in an arrow function

Comment: You're welcome!! You are mutating the state by doing `todo.completed = !todo.completed`, try using the `spread` operator instead. But your code isn't wrong. Just anti pattern